# mongodb findOneAndUpdate replace document instead of updating specified field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I don't understand the method findOneAndUpdate of mongodb or it's a bug, I want to update a document :

```
/// The document
{
    "name":"Mary",
    "infos":{
        "cp":"976",
        "tel":"0766553355",
        "adress":"10 av alabama"
    }
}
/// The update 
/*
    req.body is an array of infos :
    "infos":{
        "cp":"222",
        "tel":"888888888",
    }
*/
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.body._id}, {req.body}, {upsert:false}, .... )
```

Here the result is :

```
{
    "name":"Mary",
    "infos":{
        "cp":"222",
        "tel":"888888888",
    }
}
```

The result I want is :

```
{
    "name":"Mary",
    "infos":{
        "cp":"222",
        "tel":"888888888",
        "adress":"10 av alabama"
    }
}
```

And the address line is gone, I just want to update specified field and not to remove unspecified field.

Can someone please help?

====== UPDATE =========
The real question is : how to update each of the subdocument field ?

Thank you.

Comment: Your problem is that you are telling MongoDB to set the field `infos` to a value that is a new subdocument. So you are entirely replacing the `infos` field with a new value. What you actually want is something like this where you update individual fields (and not all of them) inside your `infos` subdocument: `{ $set: { "infos.cp":"222", "infos.tel":"888888888" } }`

Comment: @dnickless No. Mongoose actually applies the `$set` for you. The reverse is true here that you actually have to set an option not to, so there's something not true about the question. This does not reproduce. I suggest that in order to show it's a bug you actually show the output when you enable debugging `mongoose.set('debug', true)`. But I suspect this will actually show the `overwrite` option in the command, which means something you have is actually turning that on.

Comment: @NeilLunn: The `$set` is wrong for Mongoose, ok - I posted a plain MongoDB syntax. Still, I would guess that a `{ "infos.cp": "222", "infos.tel":"888888888" }` should yield the desired result? Not sure, though, I'm not using Mongoose...

Comment: @dnickless The first part of the comment was for you. The main body is for the OP. They need to prove they are not specifying the `overwrite`, if not explicitly then by plugin. I say that's the only reproducible way the result happens. Therefore I expect to see the log output from the OP before considering that this is anything other than what the solution on the duplicate already explains.

Comment: Hello all, thanks for your reply, even i add or remove the $set, the expected result is not good